# How to get count of files created/modified today in a folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-10

Below command gives me count of files in a folder, I want the count of today's created/modified files in this folder, TIA.

```
set LocalFolder=D:\Myfolder
SET file_to_be_copied_Cnt=0
for %%o IN (%LocalFolder%/*.*) DO (       
      SET /A file_to_be_copied_Cnt=file_to_be_copied_Cnt + 1   
)
echo %file_to_be_copied_Cnt%
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```cmd
forfiles /P "%LocalFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" | find /C "_"
```

Or this if you want to include sub-directories:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "%LocalFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" | find /C "_"
```

How it works:

- [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) returns a `_` character for each file modified today (`/D +0` means modified on date of today or newer);
- the [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) query avoids directories to be regarded/counted;
- [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) counts (`/C`) the amount of returned lines containing `_` characters;

---

To assign the resulting number to a variable, use a [`for /F` lop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F %%N in ('forfiles /P "%LocalFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" ^| find /C "_"') do set "NUMBER=%%N"
echo %NUMBER%
```

Or:

```cmd
for /F %%N in ('forfiles /S /P "%LocalFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" ^| find /C "_"') do set "NUMBER=%%N"
echo %NUMBER%
```

Note the escaped pipe `^|`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not actually copying the files, just counting them, you could probably use this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "LocalFolder=D:\MyFolder"
Set "i=0"
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'RoboCopy "%LocalFolder%" Null /S /MaxAge:1 /L /XJ /NS /NC /NDL /NP /NJH /NJS'
) Do Set /A i+=1
Echo %i% files modified today
Pause
```

If you're also copying the files and need to know the number copied then you could probably use this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcDir=D:\Projects"
Set "DstDir=E:\Backups"
Set "i=0"
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'RoboCopy "%SrcDir%" "DstDir" /S /MaxAge:1 /XJ /NS /NC /NDL /NP /NJH /NJS'
) Do Set /A i+=1
Echo %i% files copied
Pause
```

Comment: This returns files that are at most 24 hours old, which is not the same as today's files...